# Is pig.temp.dir property mandatory?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, hdfs

```
Pig Execution Mode = Local
```

In that case do we need to set pig.temp.dir=/temp property and this /temp folder needs to be present inside HDFS.

Note:

**Storing Intermediate Results**

Pig stores the intermediate data generated between MapReduce jobs in a temporary location on HDFS. This location must already exist on HDFS prior to use. This location can be configured using the pig.temp.dir property. The property's default value is "/tmp" which is the same as the hardcoded location in Pig 0.7.0 and earlier versions.

As per: http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.14.0/start.html#req **Storing Intermediate Results** heading

Comment: In local mode execution no MapReduce jobs will be used by pig, hence the property pig.temp.dir is irrelevant.

Comment: Thank you @donut for your ans got your point.

Answer (score 0):

You'll still need to have some temp directory, but it needs to be present in your local file system. In local mode Pig (and MapReduce) does all operations on local filesystem by default.